# How to disable an ICMPv4/v6 Echo Request?

Tags: powershell, icmp

I would like to know if there is an opportunity in powershell to disable ICMP Types like "Echo Request"

I found something like `netsh advfirewall add rule name"ICMP Allow incoming V4 echo request"` for IPv4 to add an "Echo Request"

Comment: Disable ICMP requests, or allow?

Comment: @Jelphy Sounds like he wants to deny all ICMP ECHO (ping) requests.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this natively in PowerShell (no need for `netsh`). To configure Windows Firewall to disable ICMP echo requests, use the following code:

```
$fw = @{
    DisplayName = "Disable inbound ICMP"
    Direction = "Inbound"
    Protocol = "ICMPv4"
    ICMPType = 8
    Action = "Block"
}

New-NetFirewallRule @fw
```

Note: this requires PowerShell version 5+

Comment: Can I also look for existing "NetFirewallRules"? So if someone would have added "@fw"?